# Finding Geometric sum using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to better understand recursion. I am writing a basic geometric series method which I know could be done easier with a loop but that is not the purpose. The method is producing the currect output for the values of 0 and 1 which is simply 1 and 1.5. But for 2 it is outputting 1.25 when it should be 1.75. Any pointers on a better way to approach this?

```
public static double geometricSum(int n) {
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    n = n * 2;
    return 1.0 / n + geometricSum((int) (1/Math.pow(2, n)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is the cast to int, giving the wrong result, already described by [reyeselda95](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7770792/reyeselda95).

There is a second problem hidden, which is that if you fix that you get this:

```
public static double geometricSum(double n) {
    System.err.println("Calling with " + n);
    if(n == 0){
      return 1;
    }
    n = n * 2;
    return 1.0 / n + geometricSum((1/Math.pow(2, n)));
  }
```

Calling this with the provided value of 2, leads to a loop between calls with the following values, leading to a stack overflow.

```
...
Calling with 0.4999999999999999
Calling with 0.5000000000000001
Calling with 0.4999999999999999
Calling with 0.5000000000000001
...
```

This may be the function you are looking for, if I understand correctly:

```
public static double geometricSum(int count) {
    if (count == 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    return geometricSum(count-1) + Math.pow(2, -count);
}
```

Comment: I removed the cast but now my editor is saying there is an error

Comment: Could you confirm if the last code block works for you, just to check I understand what you want to do

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are casting a float into a int.

```
1/(2^2)=1/4=0.25 --> 0
```

As you are passing your float as an int you're not getting your thing working propperly.
So 0.25 + geometricSum(0)=1.25.
On the first one happens the same. you pass the 0.5, but turned into an int so you.re not getting your aproximation propperly done.

As an advice, ALWAYS put `()` on your math functions in order to make the program, and you yourself, understand in which order it computes the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't cast float to int;
2. When using float, are you sure your formula is correct? The recursion breaks if an argument is zero, but you will get StackOverflowError when passing the result of 1.0/Math.pow(2, n) to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is my python code:

```
 def geometricSum(k):
     if k == 0:
         return 1
     return 1/2**k + geometricSum(k-1)


 k = int(input()) 
 print(geometricSum(k))
```

This is all about the **power of 2** i.e. **2 Pow n** where **n** is an integer.

> Here Recursion is used to get the sequence of values for **n**.
>   In my case I've to calculate the value for **1/(2 pow n)**.